# content-type header being overwritten during POST request

Tags: json, post, python-requests, response, content-type

I have a web service that is making a HTTP POST request to "abc" API. For the POST request I need to have 3 things in the header , the customer id, secret key and content-type. For this POST request I will also have a raw json object in the request body. Upon successful POST, the abc API will return a response. The issue I'm having is the web service is modifying the "content-type" of the header to "text/xml" automatically even if I have it as "application/json".

I have to create a temporary workaround before the the bug in the web service is fixed. I was thinking of creating a proxy server on google app engine that I would make the request to instead. This proxy server would need to have code to correct the header type to "application/json", send the request with the original request header + request body and get the response from "abc" API.

How can I prevent this from happening? I have run POST tests on the API from Postman and I get the correct response from it. It is only when I do the POST request from my web service that the content-type is being overriden at the time of the request. I am not familiar with header content-type.

Comment: Let me see if I have understood this correctly. You have an HTML form that produces an AJAX request to your server, and this uses JSON. From your server, you make a call to a third-party API, which accepts XML and not JSON. Is that a reasonable summary?

Comment: It seems that this would be fixed on your server-side - you receive JSON from the client, you send in XML to the third party, you receive XML from the third party, you send back JSON to the client. However I am not sure what your choices are - what is the difference between "fix this bug in the integration software" and "proxy between the client integration software and 3rd party ABCD API" - are you wanting the browser to call the third-party directly?

Comment: The correct course of action is to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60538094/edit), not duplicate it. I have copied the duplicate here, minus some technical writing amendments.